# Windows installation error

Tags: windows, installation

Today I encountered really new and strange problem during windows installation. I tried to install windows 7 on a Fujitsu Siemens notebook and on a step of installation I got an error :" can't install selected language". And after this installation fails.
I'm trying to install Russian language and I see such an error first time.
can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0):

Once you try to install in English and if the same problem exists Install the OS from another DVD or another source.Then you change the language to Russian directly from Windows.